# OpenLayers mobile screen and reppeating map with vector layers

Tags: android, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using the Openlayers.mobile.js library to embed an OSM in an Android application.

PROBLEM OF SCREEN DIMENSIONS

The first problem that I have is that when I zoom to level 0, for example in portrait, instead of showing the whole planet map and fill in black the extra top and bottom of the screen, it looks like it does the opposite: zoom to max extent vertically and cut the extra horizontal sides of the map.

If I set a maxExtent(-180,-90,180,90) the map has the same relative position to the screen and it doesn't let me move the map, so the two extra sides are not accessible.

Is like if it is considering the screen dimensions to be the inverse, but if I do it in landscape, I get just a center piece of the map in the screen.

My ideal desire would be to have all the map in the screen and filling with black all the extra screen. In both cases, landscape and portrait.

PROBLEM OF REPETITION

Since I cannot fix correctly the maxExtent of the map, it starts repeating itself when panning horizontally. I use vector layers that draw polygons dynamically. When the user moves the map, sometimes it moves some points of the polygon to x+360º and, therefore, when closes the polygon it shows a strange shape. (It closes the polygon with a mix of x-points and x+360 points.

Is there a way to tell the vector layer that I want all the points to be the closest ones and then he can decide if the whole polygon should be at x or x+360?
Is there a way to block map repetition or to repeat the vector layer the same way the map is repeating (allowing to show the same country/polygon in two places of the map (x and x+360º)?

NOTE: the points are just moved when the polygon lies between two maps, if not is the whole polygon that is moved. I need to tell the constructor Polygon that the polygon is closed by proximity not by points in a single map. So, the points p1=(-179,0) and p2=(179,0) should be closed without passing by the point (0,0) but passing by the point (180,0)=(-180,0).

SOME CODE

Mobile.js:

```
// initialize map when page ready
var map;

// Get rid of address bar on iphone/ipod
var fixSize = function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    document.body.style.height = '100%';
    if (!(/(iphone|ipod)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))) {
        if (document.body.parentNode) {
            document.body.parentNode.style.height = '100%';
        }
    }
};
setTimeout(fixSize, 700);
setTimeout(fixSize, 1500);

    var init = function () {
    // create map
    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        theme: null,
        numZoomLevels: 18,
        controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation({
                dragPanOptions: {
                    enableKinetic: true
                }
            })
        ],
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap", null, {
                transitionEffect: 'resize'
            })
        ],
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
        zoom: 0
    });
};
```

index.html->periodic drawing function:

```
    //Stations      
    if(Math.abs(sc_altitude-sc_altitude_tmp)>sc_altitude_step){
        stations_area_layer.removeAllFeatures();
        for (var arrayIndex in station_areas){
            /*
            var radius = Rt*Math.sin(Math.acos(Rt/(Rt+sc_altitude-stations[arrayIndex].ellipsoid_elevation)));

            var circle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
                new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(stations[arrayIndex].longitude, stations[arrayIndex].latitude).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()),
                radius,
                30 
            );

            //circle.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4258"), map.getProjectionObject());
            var station_feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(circle, null, station_area_style);
            stations_area_layer.addFeatures([station_feature]);
            */
            var areaPoints = [];
            for (var i in station_areas[arrayIndex].points) {
                var coord = station_areas[arrayIndex].points[i];
                var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(coord.longitude, coord.latitude);
                // transform from WGS 1984 to Spherical Mercator
                point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
                areaPoints.push(point);
            }               
            areaPoints.push(areaPoints[0]);

            var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(areaPoints);
            var geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]);
            var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, null, station_area_style);
            stations_area_layer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
        }

        sc_altitude_tmp = sc_altitude;
    }
```

index.html->head:

```
<head>
    <title>OpenLayers Mobile</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/default/style.mobile.css" type="text/css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="interface.js"></script>
<!--<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>-->
<script src="OpenLayers.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="proj4js/proj4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greatCircle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greatcirclemod.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="proj4js/data/tmerc.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="proj4js/data/merc.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="proj4js/data/EPSG31466.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="proj4js/data/EPSG31467.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="proj4js/data/EPSG900913.js"></SCRIPT>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/counter_orthodrome.js"></script>-->
<style>
        html, body {
            margin  : 0;
            padding : 0;
            height  : 100%;
            width   : 100%;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            html, body {
                height  : 117%;
            }
        }
        #map {
            width    : 100%;
            position : absolute;
            height   : 100%;
        }
        .olControlAttribution {
            position      : absolute;
            font-size     : 10px;
            bottom        : 0 !important;
            right         : 0 !important;
            background    : rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            font-family   : Arial;
            padding       : 2px 4px;
            border-radius : 5px 0 0 0;
        }
        #title, #tags, #shortdesc {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no answers, I am going to explain what I discovered and the workarounds I did:

FOR THE SCREEN DIMENSIONS:

The map has different extensions when and when not using map wrappingDateLine.
The map has fixed max zoom levels (coming from the tile providers). This zoom levels are not taking into account the screen boundaries nor the pixel density because the zoom level 1 in a smartphone is completely different to zoom 1 in a tablet. There is no easy way to make the map fit the screen always in any device.

It is possible that playing with setMaxResolution and MinResolution this behavior can be improved.

FOR THE REPETITION OF LAYERS:

Now i am not wrapping date line but I think my workaround will work in all cases:

I need a way to distinguish if the polygon contains inside some of the poles and which one. Luckily for me I had a way to distinguish it using the same library that produces the points for the polygon.

With this distinction I can create two different functions that will behave in a different way:

For closed polygons:

the idea is to detect a change in longitude sign, discarding the change of sign in the middle of the map (0º), and alternate the filling of two arrays of points when detecting the jump. In addition, at each jump detected, we are going to add the limit points of the partial polygons by choosing -180/180 in longitude and the average between the two latitudes (before and after the point).

We end up with two arrays that can be used to build the polygons. In the following function, arrayIndex corresponds to the index of an array of "stations", each station contains a set of points to create a polygon.

```
function paintClosedArea(arrayIndex){
var areaFirst = [];
var areaSecond = [];
var area_tmp_long = 0, area_tmp_lat = 0;
var first = true;
for (var i in station_areas[arrayIndex].points) {
    var coord = station_areas[arrayIndex].points[i];
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(
                        coord.longitude, 
                        coord.latitude
        ).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());

    if((i!=0) && ((coord.longitude*area_tmp_long)<0) && (Math.abs(coord.longitude)>90.0) && (area_tmp_long+coord.longitude<90.0)){
        var avg_lat = (coord.latitude+area_tmp_lat)/2;
        if(coord.longitude > 0)
            var new_lon = -179.999999;
        else
            var new_lon = 179.999999;
        if(first){
            areaFirst.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(new_lon, avg_lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));
            areaSecond.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-new_lon, avg_lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));
            first=false;
        }else{
            areaFirst.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-new_lon, avg_lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));
            areaSecond.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(+new_lon, avg_lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));
            first=true;
        }
    }
    area_tmp_lat = coord.latitude;
    area_tmp_long = coord.longitude;

    if(first){
        areaFirst.push(point);
    }else{
        areaSecond.push(point);
    }                   
}               
if(areaFirst.length>0){
    //areaFirst.push(areaFirst[0]);
    var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(areaFirst);
    var geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]);
    var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, null, station_area_style);
    stations_area_layer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
}
if(areaSecond.length>0){
    //areaSecond.push(areaSecond[0]);
    var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(areaSecond);
    var geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]);
    var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, null, station_area_style);
    stations_area_layer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
}
}
```

For the open polygons, that is the polygons that contain a pole inside, we are just going to produce one array of points (one polygon), but in this case, when we detect a jump in the date line, we add 4 points: the two limits -180,180 but also the two corners -180,90 180,90 in case of containing the North pole, -180,-90 180,-90 if it contains the South pole.

By giving these additional 4 points, the polygon will be closed filling the hole pole, if not the result doe not enclose the pole and the polygon cuts itself.

In the following function, arrayIndex is the same as before, type is 1 if the polygon contains the North pole and 2 if it is the South pole:

```
function paintOpenArea(arrayIndex,type){
var areaFirst = [];
var areaSecond = [];
var area_tmp_long = 0, area_tmp_lat = 0;
var first = true;
for (var i in station_areas[arrayIndex].points) {
    var coord = station_areas[arrayIndex].points[i];
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(
                        coord.longitude, 
                        coord.latitude
        ).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());

    if((i!=0) && ((coord.longitude*area_tmp_long)<0) && (Math.abs(coord.longitude)>90.0) && (area_tmp_long+coord.longitude<90.0)){
        var avg_lat = (coord.latitude+area_tmp_lat)/2;
        if(coord.longitude > 0)
            var new_lon = -179.999999;
        else
            var new_lon = 179.999999;
        if(type == 1)
            var new_lat = 90.0;
        else
            var new_lat = -90.0;

        areaFirst.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(new_lon, avg_lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));
        areaFirst.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(new_lon, new_lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));
        areaFirst.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-new_lon, new_lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));
        areaFirst.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-new_lon, avg_lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));

    }
    area_tmp_lat = coord.latitude;
    area_tmp_long = coord.longitude;

    areaFirst.push(point);                  
}               
if(areaFirst.length>0){
    //areaFirst.push(areaFirst[0]);
    var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(areaFirst);
    var geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]);
    var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, null, station_area_style);
    stations_area_layer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
}
}
```

The function with the loop calling the two previous functions is:

```
function drawStationsAreas(){
if(Math.abs(sc_altitude-sc_altitude_tmp)>sc_altitude_step){
    stations_area_layer.removeAllFeatures();
    for (var arrayIndex in station_areas){
        if(station_areas[arrayIndex].type==0)
            paintClosedArea(arrayIndex);
        else
            paintOpenArea(arrayIndex,station_areas[arrayIndex].type);

    }

    sc_altitude_tmp = sc_altitude;
}
}
```

We have to be aware that these functions are not perfect and it's very important to have the sets of points of the input not starting by one of the extremes (the jump in date line will not be detected).

IF ANYONE DOES NOT AGREE WITH SOME OF THE STATEMENTS OR IT HAS COMMENTS OR SUGGESTIONS ABOUT THESE FUNCTIONS PLEASE DON'T HESITATE TO COMMENT THE ANSWER.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this. In OL 5, you may not need to split the closed polygon, you can just adjust the longitude of some of the points to be > 180 or < -180. This way it draws proper polygons. However, this approach doesn't work for open polygons and so your extra segments trick is still needed.